# Apply style after CSS animation without JS

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have a chained CSS animation that's mostly working fine:

```
#product {
    background: red;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    border: none;
    left: -22%;
    top: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    animation: product_across 2s linear, product_down 1s;
    animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
}
@-moz-keyframes product_across {
    from { left: -22%; }
    to { left: 98%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes product_down {
    from { top: 40%; left: 98%; }
    to { top: 98%; left: 128.5%; }
}
```

The thing is, after the first animation (`product_across`) has finished, I want to apply a style. Not animate to it, just apply it.

Does CSS3 allow for this? I guess I'm looking for a sort of "on animation end" property, or something.

For the moment I'm getting round it with:

```
@-moz-keyframes product_down {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); top: 40%; left: 98%; }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); top: 98%; left: 128.5%; }
}
```

...where the rotation is the style I wish to apply. By setting the `from`/`to` states to the same value for this property, it effectively does what I want, but I can't help thinking there must be a better way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do need to use `animation-fill-mode:forwards` as Devin suggests, but this only works for properties set in the animation. In order to set properties *other than the ones you want actually animated*, you must make them part of the animation by adding them to the very end like so:

```
@keyframes  {
  /* ... Your original keyframes (except the last) ... */
  99.99% { /* ... The properties of something you want to change ... */ }
  100% { /*... Your original end properties and the changed properties ...*/ }
}
```

for example:

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    99.999% { background:blue; }
    100% { transform:rotate(360deg); background:red; }
}
```

By having the difference between the two end keyframes as really small, it will jump to the new styles no matter what the `animation-duration` is.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vksqy3dt/)

The other, more common, way to get this effect is to use Javascript's [`animation-end`](http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback)

Answer (score 10):

yes, you need to use [Animation Fill Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

Simply define that style as the last keyframe and then you add this to #product

```
#product{-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; animation-fill-mode:forwards;}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox a property with `!important` will override the property previously set with a `@keyframe`:

```
#product .newStyle {
    top: 90% !important;
    left: 120% !important;
}
```

Unfortunately this fails on Chrome and Edge.